# Почему не работает функция return float(value) (не возвращает переменную другого типа)?

Tags: python, типы-данных

Помогите, пожалуйста!
Хочу функцию, изменяющую тип переменной, получаемой через `input` в формате str на тип float.

```
def num (x):
    while isinstance(x, str):
        try:
            return float(x)
        except ValueError:
            input ("one more time")
            break 

a = input ("Go: ")
num (a)
print (a)
print (type (a))
```

По итогу, несмотря на то, что я ставлю `return float(x)`, вывод при помощи `print (type (a))` показывает, что тип данных введенной пользователем строки все равно остается str. Подскажите , как реализовать задамунное и возможно ли это?

Comment: `a = num(input ("Go: "))`

Comment: Мне такой вариант не подходит, нужно чтобы именно функция `num` конвертировала тип данных во флоат,  а если пользователь введет неконвертируемые данные, например, текст, то вылезал бы `input ("one more time")`, для того, чтобы он ввел именно число

Comment: Тут похоже с выводом результатов что-то: `print(num(a))` и `print(type(num(a)))`. Саму функцию ещё тестировать надо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Мне такой вариант не подходит, нужно чтобы именно функция `num` конвертировала тип данных во флоат, а если пользователь введет неконвертируемые данные, например, текст, то вылезал бы `input ("one more time")`, для того, чтобы он ввел именно число

## Решение с рекурсией

```py
def num(x):
  try:
    return float(x)
  except:
    return num(input('one more time '))

a = 2
b = '3'
c = '3aw3'

print(num(a))
print(num(b))
print(num(c))
```

Результат:

```
2.0 # вывод float(2) - успех
3.0 # вывод float('3') - успех
one more time 5da2 # вывод float('3aw3') - неудача. Повторный ввод
one more time 54d # вывод float('5da2') - неудача. Повторный ввод
one more time 4 # вывод float('54d') - неудача. Повторный ввод
4.0 # вывод float('4') - успех
```

## Решение без рекурсии

```py
def numinput(*args):
  try:
    return float(input(*args))
  except:
    while 1:
      try:
        return float(input("one more time "))
      except:
        pass

a = numinput("Введите число ")
print(a)
```

Результат:

```
Введите число 412в2
one more time -3
-3.0
```

Comment: спасибо, первое точное работает. Со вторым надо разобраться, ибо я еще даже не шарю, что делает `*args` - сижу-обтекаю после твоего ответа, в общем)

Comment: @Kaderma `*args` - "остальные аргументы". В данном случае это нужно, чтобы все аргументы, которые передаются в `numinput`, внутри передавались в `input`

Comment: похоже, что этот  `*args` сильно упрощает людям жизнь. Еще раз спасибо за ответ